# Use the same sender profile in different BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

If a I set up a new sender profile for one BU can I use it later for another BU? Would this affect in any way the deliverability, open rates or anything else? Would this require IP warm up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this sender profile is using an existing authenticated domain (either from a Sender Authentication Package or a Private Domain) - which I will strongly recommend, there is nothing preventing you to use same sender profile across multiple Business Units.

It will also utilize an existing IP address, so no IP warmup will be needed.